# iOS4: application termination event?

Tags: iphone, ios4, notifications, push, terminate

I would like to know how i can detect when an application is about to be terminated. I mean really terminated, not just going into background mode. I have used this event, and it doesn't fire :

applicationWillTerminate

What i would really like to achieve is get some kind of event or notification when the user taps Home *twice* and presses the red baloon on the app. I don't care about the application going into background mode, there are a couple of events that handle this properly and they all work fine.

I need this so that i can "inform" my server to stop sending push notifications to APNS for apps that are terminated and aren't running in the background.

If you know of an easier way to achieve this, i'd be glad to hear :)

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Angel, what you're asking for cannot be done. The app will be terminated with SIGKILL. Unstoppable, not catchable, no notifications. There is no difference between a system-initiated termination or one requested by the user.

You'll get applicationWillTerminate only if your app doesn't support background processing.

Answer (score 2):

Register your object (view controller, etc.) to listen for the [`UIApplicationWillTerminateNotification`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIApplication_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/c/data/UIApplicationWillTerminateNotification) notification, and/or override the application delegate's [`-applicationWillTerminate:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIApplicationDelegate/applicationWillTerminate%3a) method and put your code there.

Answer (score 1):

From UIApplicationDelegate docs on the matter:

> For applications that support
>   background execution, this method is
>   generally not called when the user
>   quits the application because the
>   application simply moves to the
>   background in that case. However, this
>   method may be called in situations
>   where the application is running in
>   the background (not suspended) and the
>   system needs to terminate it for some
>   reason.

Seems to me that unless your background process is actively doing something in the background (not being suspended) it the applicationWillTerminate method will never get called.

I guess it depends what you definition of "being in the background" is.

Comment: We are active (running) in the background, and do not get "applicationWillTerminate". See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

IIRC it goes like this:

On start:

- `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`
- `applicationDidBecomeActive`

Pressing home:

- `applicationWillResignActive`
- `applicationDidEnterBackground`

Coming back from home screen:

- `applicationWillEnterForeground`
- `applicationDidBecomeActive`

`applicationWillTerminate` is called when your application exits due to a call or the OS kills it for some reason.